# Why does my form url pass the same primary key for all posts?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have an HTML template where I list out posts one by one, and for some reason,

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
...
<form class='bookmark-form' method='POST' action="{% url 'add_bookmark' post.pk %}" 
          data-url='{{ request.build_absolute_uri|safe }}'> {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" value="{{post.pk}}" class="post-pk" hidden>
      <button type='submit'><img src="/img/bookmark.svg" alt=""></button>
</form>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Javascript:

```
  $('.bookmark-form').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault() 
      var $formData = $('.post-pk').val()
      var postData = {csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(), 'post-pk': $formData}
      var $thisURL = $('.bookmark-form').attr('data-url') || window.location.href 
      var form_action =  $('.bookmark-form').attr('action')
      console.log($formData)
      $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: form_action,
          data: postData,
          success: function (data) {console.log(data)},
          error: function(data) {console.log("Something went wrong!");}
      })
      return false;
  })
```

Views.py Add Bookmark Function

```
def add_bookmark(request, pk):
    if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        print(pk)
        user = request.user 
        user.bookmarks.add(post)
        user.save()
        print(user.bookmarks.all())
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'ok'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'nok'})
```

HTML Rendered Page:
[image: HTML Rendered Page]

Regardless of which bookmark button I click on, I always get the same output in my terminal and console log.

Terminal:

```
10
<QuerySet [<Post: Hogwarts, a History>, <Post: The Truth: My Parents are Dentists>, <Post: How to Organize Money: An Easy 10000 Steps>, <Post: Reallllllllly Old Post>, <Post: My First Serious Post>]>
```

Console Log:

```
10
{'result': "ok"}
```

where 10 is the primary key for the 'My First Serious Post' Post. I can't seem to find the reason why I won't get any other primary keys than 10.

Comment: The statement  var $formData = $('.post-pk').val() is causing the issue

Comment: Taking out $formData, I still run into the same issue, except this time, the 10 doesn't appear in the console log (since I can't log formData anymore). Thank you, though

Comment: You don't have to remove it, check how to get post-pk value of the form being submitted, as post-pk is a class and there will many inputs with same class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the that the form data you are selecting in not in the scope of the form submitting it;

try this:

```
var $formData = $(this).val()
```

You will have to change all your slections like this

EDIT:
To explain, when you select by class, jquery gets the value of the first element matching the class you provided. This is why you got the same data all the time, it took the values of the first from.

When you want to find values triggered by an event, it is uselful to use the `this` keyword as this will maintain the scope of the event. You can use `$(this).find('.eg')` or `$(this).closest('.eg')` to access variables